# Openmpi with mpi4py don't work on multiple nodes

Tags: python, python-2.7, openmpi, mpi4py

I have paralell python program written with mpi4py. I'm trying to make it distributed. I set up virtual machine, installed openmpi, openssh server, exchanged keys and all that. On local machine I have hostfile:

```
127.0.0.1 slots=4
192.168.1.104 slots=2
```

and i try to run program with:

```
mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hostfile python2 algen.py 0.85 0.02 20 70
```

but I get the following error:

> [Kreutz:13090] tcp_peer_recv_connect_ack: invalid header type: 0
>
> ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons. This usually is
> caused by:
>
> - not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on   one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH   settings, or
>   configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default
> - lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.   Please verify your allocation and authorities.
> - the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).   Please check with your sys admin to
>   determine the correct location to use.
> - compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required   (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and
>   consider using   one of the contrib/platform definitions for your
>   system type.
> - an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a   lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between   them.
>   Please check network connectivity (including firewalls   and network
>   routing requirements).

And i don't know what to do now. Do you have any ideas what could I try?

Comment: That is one of the best error messages that you could possibly imagine. What was the result of your own attempts to fix the situation?

Comment: first, try something very basic such as `mpirun -np 2 --hostfile hostfile hostname`. Per the log message, it should not work (so no needs to bring `mpi4py` into the picture). Then make sure the same Open MPI version is installed on your both nodes. you might also try to replace `mpirun` with its full path (e.g. `/opt/openmpi-3.0.2/bin/mpirun`) and see whether it helps.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh, you were right! On my main manjaro machine i have openmpi v3.1.1 and on virtual ubuntu it's 2.1.1. I'll try to match versions and check if it will run ;)